# What's the difference between "Extract to Method" and "Extract to Function" in Xcode Refactoring

Tags: xcode

I'm looking in the refactoring tools Xcode provides and was wondering what's the difference between "Extract to Method" and "Extract to Function".

Also, I can't seem to find an example where "Extract to Function" is available, meaning not greyed out. I assumed "Extract to Function" to be basically the same as "Extract to Method" just outside of the scope of a class/struct/enum. But even when I'm writing a global function the refactoring tool would only have "Extract to Method" available.

[image: Xcode refactoring tools]